# Optimization of JavaScript countdown

Tags: javascript, countdown

I'm not very familiar with JavaScript but I need to set up a countdown to display days, hours, minutes and seconds separately. I found following JS code, however, I'm not sure that this code is optimal. Could you please recommend me any better solution if possible?

```
<script>
        // Set countdown
        var cddate = new Date("May 31, 2019 16:55:00").getTime();
        var x = setInterval(function() {
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            var distance = cddate - now;

            // Store vars (Hours + 1 to set GTM+1 time)
            document.getElementById("d").innerHTML = Math.floor(distance / (86400000));
            document.getElementById("h").innerHTML = Math.floor((distance % (86400000)) / (3600000)) + 1;
            document.getElementById("m").innerHTML = Math.floor((distance % (3600000)) / (60000));
            document.getElementById("s").innerHTML = Math.floor((distance % (60000)) / 1000);
        }, 1000);
</script>
```

I would like to display individual variables from JS as:
`<p id="x"></p>`

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does it count down? I don't understand what your issue is

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question seems more suitable for another network, which is **code review**: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ . As long as some code is working as expected but needs to be **optizimed**, codereview is the correct network to post into.

Comment: Does it work for what you need? Then it is probably _good enough_. And if you still think you need something “better” - then you should start by learning some JS basics first, so that you have a basis to decide on what is “good” or “better” in the first place. (Asking for “better” without specifying _any_ criteria does of course not make much sense to begin with.)

Comment: `I would like to display individual variables from JS as: <p id="x"></p>` Is that a second question? Because it seems mostly unrelated to optimizing that countdown code.

Comment: *"I'm not sure that this code is optimal."* imo. it's pretty close to optimal. especially as you don't increment/decrement seconds, minutes, etc wich is extremely inaccurate in JS. Why do you think it is not good / what troubles you about this code?

Comment: Thank you for your replies. It actually works, I was just worried that this code is unnecessary complicated for computing and there might be better (to significantly improve performance) solution. @briosheje I thought, this community would help me with optimization too, I will use codereview next time, as you recommend.

Answer (score 1):

you have asked 2 questions here.

> 1st question: you are already using a better solution.
>
> 2nd question: I think you are asking for your countdown to be shown in a single `p` tag. If I'm right then try this code.

```js
var cddate = new Date("May 31, 2019 16:55:00").getTime();
        var x = setInterval(function() {
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            var distance = cddate - now;
            var count = Math.floor(distance / (86400000)) + ' ' + (Math.floor((distance % (86400000)) / (3600000)) + 1) + ':' + Math.floor((distance % (3600000)) / (60000)) + ':' + Math.floor((distance % (60000)) / 1000);
            document.getElementById("xid").innerHTML = count;
        }, 1000);
```

```html
<p id="xid"></p>
```